# How to get a contact number in J2ME?

Tags: java-me

How to get a contact number in J2ME program?

Comment: What's a "contect number"?  Can you give us some more context?

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed the crabby responses to almost all of your questions. If you want good answers: You'll need to stop "plz Rply asap" because that just makes S.O. users crabby (sad but true), you'll need to ask very specific questions like "Here's my program, I'm stuck because I want _____. I tried _____, but it didnt work because ______" (Please don't actually use the blanks, fill them in correctly).

Comment: Thank you, cpfohl, for these good suggestions about asking better questions.  @ManMohan you may want to also re-read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about [PIM API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/pim/pim5/) (JSR 75).